# Global event in UWP

Tags: events, uwp

In WPF, you can get global mouse events by registering in App.xaml.cs as below.

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnPreviewMouseDown));
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.PreviewMouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnPreviewMouseUp));
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.PreviewKeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDownEvent));
```

In UWP, I wonder how I can get a PointerMoved event from App.xaml.cs in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the main window content with the singleton class provided:

```
Window.Current.Content.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
Window.Current.Content.Pointer... // etc...
```